# GridView - accessing elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a GridView control that lists Customer objects with these fields:
ID, FirstName, LastName, and SignUpDate.

I need to add a fifth column ('Edit') to the GridView control that allows me
to edit that particular Customer. It could be a LinkButton or a BoundButton.

So when the 'Edit' link/button is clicked, I want to access the Id and pass
it to the Click event. I have a method that takes an Id and edits the Customer.

The GridView is bound to a List of Customer objects. How can I do this?

```
<asp:GridView ...>
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Customer ID"  DataTextField="Id" />
        <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="First Name"   DataTextField="FirstName" />
        <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Last Name"    DataTextField="LastName" />
        <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Member Since" DataTextField="SignUpDate" />
        <'Edit' link/button here. Want to pass 'Id' to a method when clicked />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

customerList.DataSource = customerList; // this is List<Customer>
customerList.DataKeyNames = new string[] {"Id"};
customerList.DataBind();
```

Comment: I suggest reading a good tutorial or book on GridViews. The edit feature is built in and all you have to do is to add a CommandField column. Do not reinvent the wheel, use an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a commandfield to define your edit column.

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
```